# Alt keyup lost when doing alt-tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm detecting alt with the following code. It works, but when I do <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to another program, I get a keydown of 18 (alt) and no keyup, and <kbd>alt</kbd> remains pressed. How can I solve this?

```
var altPressed = false;

$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    console.log("keydown", evt.which);
    switch (evt.which) {
    case 18: 
        altPressed = true;
    break;
    }
}).keyup(function(evt) {
    console.log("keyup", evt.which);
    switch (evt.which) {
    case 18: 
        altPressed = false;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> removes the focus on your main window, thus the `keyup` event will not fire.

Here's a probable solution you could use. I'm not sure if escape is being registered from `which` though, might have to use `keyCode` instead.

Example:

```
var altPressed = false;

$(document).keydown(function(evt) {
    console.log("keydown", evt.which);
    switch (evt.which) {
    case 18:
        altPressed = true;
        break;
    case 9: //tab key
    case 27: //escape key
        if(altPressed) {
             altPressed = false;
        }
    break;
    }
}).keyup(function(evt) {
    console.log("keyup", evt.which);
    switch (evt.which) {
    case 18: 
        altPressed = false;
    break;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Nathan points out correctly: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> removes the focus on the main window, thus the keyup event will not fire.

Here is a solution that does not require jQuery **and** works for every focus loss:

### Using the Blur event

Here is a VanillaJS example using your code, read more about the blur event in MDN docs

```
let altPressed = false;

function keyDownHandler(evt) {
  if(evt.key === "Alt")
    altPressed = true
}

function keyUpHandler(evt) {
  if(evt.key === "Alt")
    altPressed = false
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler)
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpHandler)
window.addEventListener('blur', keyUpHandler)
```

*Note: same as with @Nathans answer, this will not know whether the key is still down when moving back to the page (but with alt+tab it would not anyways).*